# Don't have access to Ubuntu any more

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have both Ubuntu and Windows operating systems on my computer. A few days ago I was on Windows operating system when a message asked me give permission for a Windows system update. I thought it was from Microsoft and allowed it to make changes to my pc and the following day when I tried to access Ubuntu there was no options for me to choose Ubuntu. When I boot my computer only a black screen appears and the the Windows appear. No Ubuntu or the options to choose between Ubuntu Or Windows. Now I have lost all my works for my study with it.
My question is: does anyone know how I could reverse the condition to my original state where I can access both Ubuntu & Windows OS?

Comment: The Windows update turned on all the features you may have turned off such as secure boot. In Windows review and turn of theses features again. You may also need to repair the grub boot loader.

Comment: Run [Boot-Repar]{https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from a live USB . Once the app opens, click on the big **Recommended Repair** button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Most of the solutions provided seem a bit complicated to me. To be honest I am not computer stuffs savvy. But I will try to implement them. Thanks for all the help provided though.